# Meaning of the word 'wurst'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, spoken-english

> "I'm real sorry to 'ear that, sir. There's two or three o' my pals, anyhow, who remember 'er clear as anything, though we did only see 'er that **wurst**. Yes, we remember 'her all right."
>
> Reference: Good-bye Mr. Chips, Chapter, 6

In Dictionary, the word **wurst** means sausage that doesn't match the context here. Is it some typo mistake? or, is there any contextual reference and it conveys some particular information?

Comment: That's not what it says. Check [any other copy of the story](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1934/04/good-bye-mr-chips/651988/) and you'll have more luck. There's another typo in this same section: "(apostrophe)her" should be "(apostrophe)er" (**'er**), like in the rest of the quote, to indicate a dialect where initial H is not pronounced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like it's just a typo. The version I found online from [project gutenberg](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks05/0500111h.html#chap6) has **wunst**, which is most likely just **once**, but pronounced with the distinctive accent of the character.

Comment: Wells was fond of representing working-class speech phonetically - see Kipps' remarks about 'toce' (toast) - he is widely supposed to represent the young Wells.